# How to convert a PDF to grayscale in Python

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript, grayscale

Is it possible to convert a PDF file into its grayscale equivalent using a Python library? I have tried the [ghostscript](https://pypi.org/project/ghostscript/) module:

```
import locale
from io import BytesIO
import ghostscript as gs

ENCO = locale.getpreferredencoding()
STDOUT = BytesIO()
STDERR = BytesIO()

with open('adob_in.pdf', 'r') as infile:
    ARGS = f"""DUMMY -sOutputFile=adob_out.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite
     -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray
     -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH {infile.name}"""

    ARGSB = [arg.encode(ENCO) for arg in ARGS.split()]

    gs.Ghostscript(*ARGSB, stdout=STDOUT, stderr=STDERR)

print(STDOUT.getvalue().decode(ENCO))
print(STDERR.getvalue().decode(ENCO))
```

The standard out and error streams are:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.52 (2020-03-19)
Copyright (C) 2020 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
```

Unfortunately, the grayscale PDF is corrupted. Indeed, debugging with Ghostscript shows the following error:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.52 (2020-03-19)
Copyright (C) 2020 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
   **** Error: Cannot find a 'startxref' anywhere in the file.
               Output may be incorrect.
   **** Error:  An error occurred while reading an XREF table.
   **** The file has been damaged.  This may have been caused
   **** by a problem while converting or transfering the file.
   **** Ghostscript will attempt to recover the data.
   **** However, the output may be incorrect.
   **** Error:  Trailer dictionary not found.
                Output may be incorrect.
   No pages will be processed (FirstPage > LastPage).

   **** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
   **** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
   **** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
   **** specification.

   **** The rendered output from this file may be incorrect.
GS>
```

Note that the string `ARGS` contains valid ghostscript code (tested in Linux command line, with `GPL Ghostscript 9.52`) and `ARGSB` is just the corresponding binary representation of the strings:

```
print(ARGSB)
[b'DUMMY', b'-sOutputFile=adob_out.pdf', b'-sDEVICE=pdfwrite', b'-sColorConversionStrategy=Gray', b'-dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray', b'-dNOPAUSE', b'-dBATCH', b'adob_in.pdf']
```

How could this task be properly done? My example input and output files can be found [here](https://gofile.io/d/9ob0fp). Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: To be honest this is not really a Ghostscript question, since you say it works correctly from the command shell. If it doesn't work the way you are using it, then that's likely to be a problem in the wrapper you are using. However it would help to see **all** of the back channel from Ghostscript, not just the bit you've shown.

Comment: @KenS thanks a lot for your comment. I have added the full output from Ghostscript. Yes, I also think it is a problem of the Python wrapper. To be honest, I don't know if this library is the best solution to the problem, that is why I asked for ideas.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't readily comment about the Python library, on the grounds that I know absolutely nothing about Python. Ghostscript is clearly opening **a** file, but I wonder if its actually opening the right file. The error message is pretty clear that its not a PDF file. In fact that looks rather like its trying to open the output file as an input file. Do you get an output file at all (more than 0 bytes) ? If so can you put it somewhere public ? Can you print out what's actually contained in *ARGSB ?

Comment: @KenS thank you again for your interest. I have edited my question to add more information (input and output files). The example input file is `17K` size versus `2.7K` in the output. I have also added the arguments I pass to the `gs` wrapper, the first one is a dummy one.

Comment: Ah, I misread your original post! I assumed that the back channel output was from the Python run, not from reopening the output PDF file.... Yes the output file is partially correct, it contains the page content stream, but its missing an awful lot of other stuff, its not a valid PDF file, it appears to have been truncated. I would imagine this is due to some error while running the Python code. Is there any way to get the output of stdout and stderr during the python conversion ? It appears to me that something is failing there so that only part of the PDF file is being written.

Comment: @KenS I have added the standard out and error streams in the question body. The stderr is empty, and stdout looks normal to me, no?

Comment: It appears to be, yes. I'm afraid at that point there's nothing further I can contribute. Since the procedure works normally from the command line the only possibility I can think of is that somehow the process is being terminated before it is complete. But I'm not able to offer any insights on what is going on there, I know nothing about python.

Comment: I see that you could spawn a process using Python, rather than using the bindings, you might like to give that a try and see what happens. The code I see looks like : os.system("gs -sOutputFile=adob_out.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH <path>adob_in.pdf")  Obviously you will know better than me how to modify that appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do it via ghostscript but the following code using [pdf2image](https://pypi.org/project/pdf2image/) and [img2pdf](https://pypi.org/project/img2pdf/) serves the purpose:

```
from os.path import join
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory
from pdf2image import convert_from_path # https://pypi.org/project/pdf2image/
from img2pdf import convert # https://pypi.org/project/img2pdf/

with TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir: # Saves images temporarily in disk rather than RAM to speed up parsing
    # Converting pages to images
    print("Parsing pages to grayscale images. This may take a while")
    images = convert_from_path(
        "your_pdf_path.pdf",
        output_folder=temp_dir,
        grayscale=True,
        fmt="jpeg",
        thread_count=4
    )

    image_list = list()
    for page_number in range(1, len(images) + 1):
        path = join(temp_dir, "page_" + str(page_number) + ".jpeg")
        image_list.append(path)
        images[page_number-1].save(path, "JPEG") # (page_number - 1) because index starts from 0

    with open("Gray_PDF.pdf", "bw") as gray_pdf:
        gray_pdf.write(convert(image_list))

    print("The new page is saved as Gray_PDF.pdf in the current directory.")
```

The PDF file with grayscale image will be saved as Gray_PDF.pdf in the same directory.

**EXPLANATION**:
The following code:

```
with TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir: # Saves images temporarily in disk rather than RAM. This speeds up parsing
    # Converting pages to images
    print("Parsing pages to grayscale images. This may take a while")
    images = convert_from_path(
        "your_pdf_path.pdf",
        output_folder=temp_dir,
        grayscale=True,
        fmt="jpeg",
        thread_count=4
    )
```

performs the following tasks:

1. Converts the PDF pages to grayscale images.
2. Stores it temporarily in a directory.
3. Creates a list `images` of PIL image objects

Now the following code:

```
    image_list = list()
    for page_number in range(1, len(images) + 1):
        path = join(temp_dir, "page_" + str(page_number) + ".jpeg")
        image_list.append(path)
        images[page_number-1].save(path, "JPEG") # (page_number - 1) because index starts from 0
```

saves the images again as **page_1.jpeg**, **page_2.jpeg** and so on in the same directory. It also makes a list of paths of these new images.

Finally, the following code:

```
    with open("Gray_PDF.pdf", "bw") as gray_pdf:
        gray_pdf.write(convert(image_list))
```

creates a PDF named **Gray_PDF** from the grayscale images it created previously and saves it in the working directory.

**ADDITIONAL TIP:** This method gives you a lot of flexibility if you want to perform more  Image Processing operations using OpenCV because all the pages are now in the form of images. Just make sure that all operations are inside the first `with` statement, i.e. the following:

```
with TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir: # Saves images temporarily in disk rather than RAM. This speeds up parsing
```